# Is Face recognition possible in windows phone

Tags: windows, opencv, windows-phone-7, emgucv

I want to develop an app for Face detection and recognition from a given photo based on the photos in trained set.

Will it possible to do it on windows phone 7 ?

Could you please tell me the Open CV support for windows?

Please help me

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply :)
will Face SDK support all kind of image processing like open CV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Face recognition, 
Microsoft and Nokia have develop a Beta "[Face SDK](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/e87326ba-97c7-4b7e-bea4-123853f40b4d/default.aspx)" You can try this. You've more Information in the [Nokia developper website](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Face_SDK_for_Windows_Phone_7).

For The Open Cv request, I don't understsand wath you want :) 
But maybe [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/da41847c-427d-44fb-99fa-ac937aaa6e8f/opencv-in-windows-phone-7?forum=wpdevelop) response to your request...