# Facial detection coordinates using a camera

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I need a way to grab the coordinates of the face in C# for Windows Phone 8.1 *in the camera view*. I haven't been able to find anything on the web so I'm thinking it might not be possible. What I need is the x and y (and possibly area) of the "box" that forms around the face when it is detected in the camera view. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Face recognition possible in windows phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046551/is-face-recognition-possible-in-windows-phone)

Comment: @venerik Not a duplicate. That is talking about a static photo. I am talking about the camera.

Comment: The answer to the duplicate question, had you chosen to read it, addresses both images and the camera. From the answer: "Face Tracking: This module locates the face position in real-time in a live video stream."...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code snippet (bear in mind this is part of an app from the tutorial I linked below the code. It's not copy-pasteable, but should provide some help)

```
const string MODEL_FILE = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
FaceDetectionWinPhone.Detector m_detector;
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   m_detector = new FaceDetectionWinPhone.Detector(System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(MODEL_FILE));
}

void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)  
    {
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        WriteableBitmap btmMap = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);

        //find faces from the image
        List<FaceDetectionWinPhone.Rectangle> faces =
             m_detector.getFaces(
             btmMap, 10f, 1f, 0.05f, 1, false, false);

        //go through each face, and draw a red rectangle on top of it.
        foreach (var r in faces)
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(r.X);
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(r.Y);
            int width = Convert.ToInt32(r.Width);
            int height = Convert.ToInt32(r.Height);
            btmMap.FillRectangle(x, y, x + height, y + width, System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red);
         }
        //update the bitmap before drawing it.
        btmMap.Invalidate();
        facesPic.Source = btmMap;
    }
}
```

This is taken from [developer.nokia.com](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Detecting_Faces_on_Windows_Phone)

To do this in real-time, you need to intercept the viewfinder image, perhaps using the `NewCameraFrame` method (EDIT: not sure if you should use this method or  `PhotoCamera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32` as described below. I have to leave it up to your research)
So basically your task has 2 parts:

1. Get the viewfinder image
2. Detect faces on it (using something like the code above)

If I were you, I'd first do step 2. on an image loaded from disk, and once you can detect faces on that, I'd see how to obtain current viewfinder image and detect faces on that. X,Y coordinates are easy enough to obtain once you've detected the face - see code above.

(EDIT): I think you should try using `PhotoCamera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32` method to obtain the viewfinder image. Look here [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.devices.photocamera.getpreviewbufferargb32(v=vs.105).aspx). Also, be sure to search through MSDN docs and tutorials. This should be more than enough to complete step 1.

A lot of face detection algorithms use Haar classifiers, Viola-Jones algorithm etc. If you're familiar with that, you'll feel more confident in what you're doing, but you can do without. Also, read the materials that I linked - they seem fairly good.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. This is perfect! I never thought of it that way.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Also, I edited the post slightly, mentioning PhotoCamera class that you could probably use to good effect for step (1). There were other slight changes (e.g. remarks about the code snippet provided)